# format output of row to column sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the Following Data in a table (row) format based on [Test Parameter Name].

```
[Serial Number] [Model]  [Recv_Date]      [Test Date]    [Test Parameter Name]  [Test Value]  [Test Result]  [Tester Name_ID]   [Error_Defect Code]
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/22/13 0:42   Test_1                 0             FAIL           dev04_9            DC01
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/22/13 0:42   Test_2                 100           PASS           dev04_9            DC01
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/22/13 0:42   Test_3                 0             FAIL           dev04_9            DC02
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/22/13 0:42   Test_4                 NULL          SKIPPED        dev04_9            DC02
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/22/13 0:42   Test_5                 120           PASS           dev04_9            DC03
100899000345     M9001   3/20/13 23:28    3/21/13 15:55  Test_1                 99            PASS           dev09_5            DC01
100899000345     M9001   3/20/13 23:28    3/21/13 15:55  Test_2                 101           PASS           dev09_5            DC01
100899000345     M9001   3/20/13 23:28    3/21/13 15:55  Test_3                 103           PASS           dev09_5            DC02
100899000345     M9001   3/20/13 23:28    3/21/13 15:55  Test_4                 100           PASS           dev09_5            DC02
100899000345     M9001   3/20/13 23:28    3/21/13 15:55  Test_5                 119           PASS           dev09_5            DC03
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/23/13 13:15  Test_1                 0             FAIL           dev04_9            DC01
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/23/13 13:15  Test_2                 100           PASS           dev04_9            DC01
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/23/13 13:15  Test_3                 0             FAIL           dev04_9            DC02
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/23/13 13:15  Test_4                 NULL          SKIPPED        dev04_9            DC02
100811000023     M9001   3/20/13 14:18    3/23/13 13:15  Test_5                 120           PASS           dev04_9            DC03
```

I need the output to be a single record by [Serial Number] based on max [Test Date] (a unit could run multiple times). I then need to look at all the [Test Parameter Name]'s test results to see if they PASSED or FAILED.  If multiple failures I need to display the [Error_Defect Code] by priority. Note: multiple tests are grouped into an [Error_Defect Code] and in the example data, the reporting priority of any test that fail will be: [Error_Defect Code]= "DC03", then "DC02", "DC01"....  If all tests PASS, display "DC00" for the [Error_Defect Code].  I would also like to pivot the [Test Parameter Name] to show [Test Value].

The data example only shows 5 different [Test Parameter Name] values.  in reality, my actual data has 100 different [Test Parameter Name] values with 15 different [Error_Defect Code]'s.

Hear is how I desire the output to look:

```
[Serial Number] [Model]  [Recv_Date]    [Test Date]   [Test Result] [Error_Defect Code] [Tester Name_ID]  [Test_1] [Test_2] [Test_3] [Test_4] [Test_5]...
100811000023    M9001    3/20/13 14:18  3/23/13 13:15 FAIL          DC02                dev04_9            0       100      0        NULL     120
100899000345    M9001    3/20/13 23:28  3/21/13 15:55 PASS          DC00                dev09_5            99      101      103      100      119
```

Comment: Have you tried the PIVOT operator http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx ?  If so, how far have you gotten?  You'll have to join the results of a PIVOT and the result of the query implementing the Test_Result and Error_Defect_Code logic.

Comment: If you can have unlimited number of Test Parameter Names then you will not be able to solve the problem with SQL query and will need T-SQL program.

Comment: I am trying to program in T-SQL... I have tried using the PIVOT operator, but I'm stuck trying to get all the fields to produce my desired output.

Comment: This would take more time than I have. But basically were it me, I'd look into creating a base set with a CTE, grouping the necessary values with a MAX(Test_Date), handle the Error_Defect Code with a CASE statement. I would then build a string for the PIVOTed columns and combine the two to create the result. See here for a similar scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19972321/1120991